# Condition for req.flash inside Jade template (Sails)

Tags: express, pug, connect, sails.js, connect-flash

Inside my [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) application, I am passing [flash messages](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) inside my Jade templates.
I want to display these messages inside a `<section>` html5 tag, but I don't want this tag to be present if there is no flash message.

Here is my [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/) code :

```
- var flash = req.flash('error')
if error || !!flash
  section.err= error
    | #{flash}
```

But this doesn't work: it displays right my flash messages, but also puts everytime the `<section>` tag (even if the `flash` var contains no message).

**Node :** req.flash('msgtype') is flushed at every call, so I had to put it inside a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found how to manage this, by testing `flash`'s length :

```
- var flash = req.flash('error')
if error || flash.length != 0
  section.err= error
    | #{flash}
```

Inspired from https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1054#issuecomment-29045509